# How to wait for a function to finish it's execution in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I've a function named `validityCheck()` and it's returns `valid` if an user is valid and `invalid` if the user is invalid. I need to call this function from somewhere else and use the result in `if-else` condition.

Here's the function definition (This function is defined in a plain `javascript` library name `library.js`):

```
function validityCheck(userid, serviceid, system) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("https:*******userValidation?serviceid=" + serviceid + "&userid=" + userid + "&system=" + system, function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            return data[0];
        });

    });
}
```

Now I want to do this (This code section is in my project's `controller`):

```
var validity = validityCheck($scope.userid, serviceid, 'abc');
if(validity=="VALID"){
    //do something
}else{
    //do something
}
```

I need to wait till I get the data. I think I need to use callback_ or something like that but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You dont need nor should put the check in $.ready, define it in the main scope, or better expose it as service. Wrap the code in promise for reuse. And don't use $.get, use angular $http instead. Avoid jquery if you can

Comment: @SonNguyen actually the function ```validityCheck()``` is a ```javascript``` function and defined in ```library.js``` which is a plain ```javascript``` file. I've included that library and have to use that function.

Comment: If you intend to run the function only once ($.ready only fires once) and not reuse it then fine, but you'll need to modify the code to use for your own. If you're not familiar with promise, for now the quickest way is insert your result check inside the function (after console.log(data))

Comment: @SonNguyen actually I need to check it in my project. can't do that inside the function ```validityCheck()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not return promise of angularjs `$http` and use `then` in your code like this?

```
function validityCheck(userid, serviceid, system) {
    let params = {
        userid: userid,
        serviceid: serviceid,
        system: system
    };
    let request = {
        url: "https:*******userValidation",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
        params: params
    };

    return $http(request).then((response) => {
        return response.data[0] ? response.data[0] : '';
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
validityCheck($scope.userid, serviceid, 'abc').then((validity) => {
    if (validity === "VALID") {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something
    }
});
```

P.S. Don't forget to inject angularjs $http

UPDATE: Register library.js in angular

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("yourAngularModuleName")
        .factory("LibraryFactory", LibraryFactory);

        function LibraryFactory($http) {
            // Add your functions here...
        }

})();
```

UPDATE: Plain JavaScript Using The Existing Code

```
function validityCheck(userid, serviceid, system) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.get("https:*******userValidation?serviceid=" + serviceid + "&userid=" + userid + "&system=" + system, function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            resolve(data[0]);
        });
    });
}
```

Use the same code in the USAGE that I have provided.

Comment: the function ```validityCheck($scope.userid, serviceid, 'abc')``` is defined in a ```javascript``` file. And I actually don't know how to use ```promise``` in ```javascript```  ```http``` requests.

Comment: Since I can see in your code that you are using $scope, I can say that you've registered library.js in your angular module. Can you show me the content of library.js?

Comment: here's the scenerio, though I've described in the question: I've plain ```javascript``` library name ```library.js``` where the functionn ```validityCheck(userid, serviceid, system)``` is defined. 

Now, I've included ```library.js``` in my ```angularJS``` project and I've to call this ```validityCheck(userid, serviceid, system)``` function from my project and use the returned result. 

in ```library.js``` two functions are defined, one is ```validityCheck($scope.userid, serviceid, 'abc')``` and another is ```redTobaseURL()``` which just redirects to a basic url.

Comment: How did you include the library.js to your angular project? Did you register it in your angular module as a controller, service or factory?

Comment: no, I've just included like any other ```javascript``` library ```<script src="xxxx.com/js/library.js"></script>```

Comment: What is the difference between my response and yours?

Comment: @MaximShoustin Same as yours but I'm injecting the result directly to then function chain so that you can use it directly.

Comment: @Araf I suggest that you register library.js to your angular application so that you can use its features in your library.js. I have updated the answer above to show how to register your javascript.

Comment: that would be very helpful for me too but I've to use plain ```javascript``` as this final ```library.js``` can be used somewhere else which might not be an ```angularJS``` project

Comment: I have made an edit using your existing code and return a promise.